# Помогите разобраться в PHP коде

Tags: php, sql

```
  $result = fetch(mysql_query("..."));
  $patronymic = 'history';

  function godTable($request)
  {
    if($request == 0)
    {
      mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `$name` (sol INT(11))") or die(mysql_error());
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$name` (sol) VALUES ('$inputValue')") or die(mysql_error()); 
    }
    return 1;
  }

  foreach($_POST as $inputName => $inputValue) 
  {
    $name =  $inputName . $patronymic;
    $result = godTable(mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$name` (sol) VALUES ('$inputValue')"));

  }
```

Comment: вроде бы это и так php =)

Comment: название godTable не соответствует, гораздо более подходящее - OMGTable :D

Comment: Почему если код написан на php то сразу гавнокод? Завязывайте с этим стереотипом.

Answer (score 3):

Так это-ж нормальный говнокод и есть:

- как всегда отсутствующие `global` в функции.
- Про то что можно сделать `create table if not exists` тоже как-то не продумано.
- обработка ошибок на уровне `die`, хотя можно было-бы использовать исключения

Comment: Проблема уже решена, зачем исключения если можно просто `if not exists`?

Да и **можно** использовать исключения абсолютно везде =)